# Classify table based on value 'moving window' range and proportions?

Tags: r, dplyr, range, classification

I have a datasets of forest stands, each containing several tree layers of different age and volume.
I want to classify the stands as `even-` or `uneven-aged`, combining volume and age data. The forest is considered `even-aged` if more then 80% of the volume is allocated to age classes within 20 years apart. **I wonder how to implement the 'within 20 years apart' condition**? I can easily calculate the sum of volume and it's share for individual tree layers (`strat`). But how to check for 'how many years they are apart?' Is it some sort of moving window?

Dummy example:

```
# investigate volume by age classes?
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(stand = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", 
                       'id2', 'id2', 'id2'),
             strat = c(1,2,3,4,
                       1,2,3),
             v = c(4,10,15,20,
                   11,15,18),
             age = c(5,10,65,80,
                     10,15,20))

# even age  = if more of teh 80% of volume is allocated in layers in 20 years range
df %>% 
  group_by(stand) %>% 
  mutate(V_tot = sum(v)) %>% 
  mutate(V_share = v/V_tot*100)
```

Expected outcome:

```
  stand strat     v   age V_tot V_share quality
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 id1       1     4     5    49    8.16 uneven-aged
2 id1       2    10    10    49   20.4  uneven-aged
3 id1       3    15    65    49   30.6  uneven-aged
4 id1       4    20    80    49   40.8  uneven-aged #* because age classes 65 and 80, even less then 20 years apart have only 70% of total volume
5 id2       1    11    10    44   25    even-aged
6 id2       2    15    15    44   34.1  even-aged
7 id2       3    18    20    44   40.9  even-aged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `tidyverse` solution implementing a moving average:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(stand = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2"), strat = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3), v = c(4, 10, 15, 20, 11, 15, 18), age = c(5, 10, 65, 80, 10, 15, 20), V_tot = c(49, 49, 49, 49, 44, 44, 44), V_share = c(8.16326530612245, 20.4081632653061, 30.6122448979592, 40.8163265306122, 25, 34.0909090909091, 40.9090909090909)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df %>% 
  group_by(stand) %>% 
  mutate(range20 = map_dbl(age, ~ sum(V_share[which(abs(age - .x) <= 20)])),
         quality = ifelse(any(range20 > 80), "even-aged", "uneven-aged"))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 8
#> # Groups:   stand [2]
#>   stand strat     v   age V_tot V_share range20 quality    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 id1       1     4     5    49    8.16    28.6 uneven-aged
#> 2 id1       2    10    10    49   20.4     28.6 uneven-aged
#> 3 id1       3    15    65    49   30.6     71.4 uneven-aged
#> 4 id1       4    20    80    49   40.8     71.4 uneven-aged
#> 5 id2       1    11    10    44   25      100   even-aged  
#> 6 id2       2    15    15    44   34.1    100   even-aged  
#> 7 id2       3    18    20    44   40.9    100   even-aged
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Interesting issue, I think I have a solution using the `runner` [package](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(stand) %>% 
  mutate(
    V_tot = sum(v),
    V_share = v/V_tot*100,
    test = sum_run(
              V_share,
              k = 20L,
              idx = age,
              na_rm = TRUE,
              na_pad = FALSE
              ),
    quality = if_else(any(test >= 80), 'even-aged', 'uneven-aged')
  ) %>%
  select(-test)
```